# Finding 'arguments' in string variables?

Tags: java

I'm a fairly new Java programmer and I want to learn how to find 'arguments' in strings.

e.g.

```
String str = "The quick brown fox";
```

Alright, here we have the string we want to have the 'arguments' extracted from.

Now lets assume you guys have already given me the correct method, named args, to use for what I want.

```
System.out.println(str.args(3));
OUTPUT:
brown
```

Comment: Show some of the code you have written to implement this. 
Ok will give a hint... "string.split()" method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to this problem.

First, you can split a String into a `String[]` by using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).  This form accepts a regular expression on which to divide your string by.  Regular expressions are outside of the scope of this question, though - there are great resources for how to write those both here and on the Web.

What your expression would look like is this.  You can use `\s` to extract all whitespace; since we're in Java, we have to scape the whitespace though.

```
String[] args = str.split("\\s+");
```

Second, you have to index into the array.  Java's arrays are zero based.

Your results look like this, exploded:

```
|The|quick|brown|fox|
| 0 |  1  |  2  | 3 |
```

The length of the array itself is 4, with 3 as its highest element.  If you want "brown", you have to request the third slot in the array, or the second index position.

```
System.out.println(args[2]);  // prints brown
```